# slackware change dns permanently

Tags: dns, slackware

I have done research and can change the DNS server by editing `/etc/resolv.conf`, but it seems like every time I reboot the setting is overwritten by something else...
How can I stop whatever that edit the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your network address is being set by DHCP, for example your DSL router hands it the address, the it is probably getting the DNS servers to use via DHCP too. In this case, change the DNS settings on what-ever device is handing out the addresses via DHCP is the better way to go as it means other machines/devices that you plug in will get the right ones too.

**Edit:**
You can change what the DHCP client requests by updating its configuration file. I don't know exactly where this will be on a slackware install - on Debian and similar it is `/etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf`. Find the `request` line and remove `domain-name-servers`. You will probably find more detail in `man dhclient.conf` assuming you have the man pages installed.

But if the name servers being given out by your router (or other DHCP server) are incorrect you should change the configuration there instead so you do not have to configure each client individually.

Comment: I suspect the same problem. Also DHCP clients can be explicitly told to not alter /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: and how to tell them, geek?

Comment: yeah I did it, changed the DNS on my router and everything else works fine, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Slackware Linux (at least 13.0) uses the **dhcpcd** DHCP client to get dynamic IPs, as you can see by studying **/etc/rc.d/rc.inet1**. Quote from the manpage of dhcpcd:

```
-R, --nodns
         Don't send DNS information to resolvconf or touch
         /etc/resolv.conf.
```

However that option is not specified directly. Please see **/etc/rc.d/rc.inet1.conf**. Grep for the string **DHCP_KEEPRESOLV**. You must have that setting enabled for the config block corresponding to the correct network interface and its value must be **"yes"**.

Comment: `DHCP_KEEPRESOLV[x]="yes"` works in Slackware 12.1, just tested.